# Why is there a gap of information in Russia for human migration?

Tags: russia, prehistory, anthropology

I've noticed that in a lot of maps for human migration, there's usually a really unspecific arrow pointing from the Iran area that goes through Kazakhstan, Mongolia, and Russia to North America. These maps all seem to have this dark area with little info, why's that?

[image: Map of Human Migration]

Comment: it might be, because even today these regions are sparsely populated. And obviously they were such in the past. So what should have been pictured there?

Comment: Yeah, people find fossils, not archeologists. If there aren't any people in that area, then fossils won't be found. Totally flew by my head. I was thinking that maybe something about Mongolian conquests destroyed what was to be found.

Comment: I don't understand why you are sarcastic. Mongolian conquests lay further to the south of this "empty area", you can imagine a line between the Baikal lake and the Caspian sea - this would be the route of Mongolian conquests to Rus'. The empty area has very inhospitable climate even with modern technology (very long and cold winter, short summer when even in June can be a freezing temperature). So it is very unlikely that in prehistoric times there was any considerable population there, deserving to have an arrow of corresponding width on such a map

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic. I'm saying that the obvious answer flew over my head and I was thinking something else could've been the cause. The "yeah" is "yes, you are correct."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the dark area is central and eastern Siberia? If so, the reason for that is, that we have not found any prehistoric human fossils yet there. Siberia is very scarcely populated, so it is not very likely that someone is finding any fossils there.

Anyway, the route is just a theory and also the only plausible route for explaining human beings in the Americas (1), since Bering strait was a landmass in the past and the only landmass which connected Asia and the Americas.

(1) Another theory for example is that human beings did not went Out-of-Africa but also "emerged" in the Americas simultaneously. There are also a lot other theories.

Comment: What theory is the `"emerged" in the Americas simultaneously`?

Comment: @Andrew It is a variation of ["Out-of-America I"](http://anthropogenesis.kinshipstudies.org/anthropology-of-human-origins/out-of-america-family-of-hypotheses/) which does not require all modern humans to come from the Americas but only those humans indigenous to the Americas. It is equally unsustainable for the same reasons.

Comment: I would also like to point out that the map I pointed out is to show the lack of detail in Russia. [This is my personal favorite map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Mt-Haplogruppen-Wanderung.png/660px-Mt-Haplogruppen-Wanderung.png).

Comment: I'd feel better about upvoting this if it didn't mention any completely unscientific theories (of which there are a nearly infinite variety you didn't bother to mention) as if they are just another "theory" like the predominant scientific ones.

Comment: Good idea. *** ahem ***... Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42134/discussion-on-answer-by-acroneos-why-is-there-a-gap-of-information-in-russia-for).